# Cross thread operation issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a scenario where i have to call an instance of Form as ShowDialog().
      My code is like:

```
  Form view = ComponentFactory.GetInstance<IView>
                (viewConfig.Key) as Form;
  if (view == null)
  {
   if (_sysLog.IsErrorEnabled)
                _sysLog.Error("Invalid view configuration. Aborting!");
       throw new AbstractModelException("View not found.");
   }

  if (isFixed)
            view.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

   view.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   view.ShowInTaskbar = false;
   view.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(OnViewClosed);
   view.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(OnViewClosing);

   if (view is IView)
   {
     InitializeView((IView)view);
     ((IView)view).Tag = tag;
   }

   if (parentWindow != null && parentWindow is IWin32Window)
            return view.ShowDialog(parentWindow as IWin32Window);
   return view.ShowDialog();
```

I have converted the references from .net 3.5 to 4.0.

```
 Error is:
  Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the          
  thread it was created on.
```

This is giving that form control is already running in UI thread.

I have tried to resolve it by

```
  if(view.InvokeRequired)
   {
     MethodInvoker method = new MethodInvoker(() => view.ShowDialog());
      DialogResult result = (DialogResult)view.Invoke(method);
    }
```

I have tried Invoke and `BeginInvoke` both. Every time InvokeRequired is false here.

I have also tried to call `view.CreateControl`, because some where i read that perhaps
  form control is not created yet and form handle is not created.
  But this also is not working.

Every time error is coming when `ShowDialog` response is returning. By ShowDialog this 
opening a form and after processing when form is closing this is returning a 
DialogResult. After that this is returning to another class from where current function is called.

Please guide.

Comment: On what thread is the form *created*? It is the *creating* thread that is important for UI controls. Which is why you should always create controls/forms *on the UI thread*... Also: are all the controls created *on the same thread* ?

Comment: There is no any thread. Here we are opening forms as View. Each views are added to app.config file. Current code is written in ViewManager.cs from where each views are opening.

Comment: If you want to be more clear, then please tell me

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) `InvokeRequired` can return `false` even in cases where `InvokeRequired` should be `true` - namely in the case that you access `InvokeRequired` before the `Handle` of that control/form (or a parent of it) has been created.

Basically your check is incomplete which leads to the result you see.

You need to check [`IsHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx) - if that is `false` then you would need to use `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` regardless of what `InvokeRequired` returns.

**BUT**:
This usually won't work robustly since `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` check which thread created `Handle` to do their magic...

Only if `IsHandleCreated` is `true` you act based on what `InvokeRequired` returns - something along the lines of:

```
if (control.IsHandleCreated)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
else 
{ 
    // in this case InvokeRequired might lie - you need to make sure that this never happens! 
    throw new Exception ( "Somehow Handle has not yet been created on the UI thread!" );
}
```

**Thus the following is important to avoid this problem**

Always make sure that the `Handle` is already created BEFORE the first access on a thread other than the UI thread.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) you just need to reference `control.Handle` in the UI thread to force it being created - in your code this must happen BEFORE the very first time you access that control/form from any thread that is not the UI thread.

Comment: Problem is... we can not through exception. The class is added in a project which is using in two places. One is desktop application, where this is working fine and opening dialog and setting values very well. Other place is Excel Add-In, from where this thing is giving error. Joke is... there is no any impact on data. Every thing is going fine in database and calculations are also fine. What we should do, so that it should not through this error.

Comment: @Abhi Sorry, but that is a completely different problem... Office-/Excel-AddIns are not mentioned anywhere in the question AND there is not enough code/information to even guess what is going on between Excel and your AddIn.